# how to get locals in Express from routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a variable defined as local on my app.js file like this (app is really express) :

```
app.locals.weather = { /* unimportant content here */ };
```

Now, I want to access that information from my index.js route to print on a ejs template. I'm trying this, but it says it is undefined:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

console.log(express.locals);
```

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.locals) states:

> You can access local variables in templates rendered within the application.

In other words, you don't have to do anything special to pass `weather` to your EJS template, by assigning it to `app.locals` you make it available through your app.

Comment: yet it doesn't render... I'm doing: <%= locals.weather%> and it is blank, I wrote locals. weather instead of only weather because in the second case an error ocurred...

Answer (score 2):

All keys created under app.locals are available directly to the template.

In your template you should not refer to it as `locals.weather`, instead try only `weather`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');
app.locals.weather = 'hot';

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('received req');
    res.render('hello');
});

app.listen(3000)
```

And the ejs template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
    hello ejs
</div>
<div>
    <%= weather %>
</div>
```

And it works